# Discord.py get uses and author from an invite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I would like to get all the invites from a discord server. I get all the invite but I want to get the author and the uses from it.
Everything works just fine except the guild.uses.

Tried to embed the things from the discord API.

"""From discord api https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Attribute   &   Method

max_age     abc.GuildChannel.invites(), Guild.invites()

max_uses   abc.GuildChannel.invites(), Guild.invites()

created_at  abc.GuildChannel.invites(), Guild.invites()

temporary abc.GuildChannel.invites(), Guild.invites()

uses abc.GuildChannel.invites(), Guild.invites()

approximate_member_count Client.fetch_invite()

approximate_presence_count Client.fetch_invite()
"""

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")
    for guild in client.guilds:
        x = await guild.invites()
        print(x)
        uses = guild.uses
        print(uses)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the [`Invite.inviter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20invites#discord.Invite.inviter) and [`Invite.uses`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20invites#discord.Invite.uses) attributes

```py
for guild in client.guilds:
    invites = await guild.invites()

    for x in invites:
        print(f"Total uses: {x.uses} Created by: {x.inviter}")
```

Comment: print(f"Total uses: {x.uses} Created by: {x.inviter}")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'uses'